# Dynamics of a Gyroscope motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, gyroscopes

If we take a gyroscope with a spinning rotor and rotate the gyroscope frame about a vertical axis or the spin axis (see reference figure), we notice that the gimbal+rotor flips about the gimbal axis.

[image: Reference Gyroscope Image]
Also, we experience significant resistance (did not quantify how much) while trying to rotate the Gyroscope frame about the vertical axis when the rotor is spinning.

So far what I've said is pure observation. My question is, what equations of motion justify the flipping of the gimbal along the gimbal axis? Also, what force is causing the gimbal to flip? It is certainly not Strong, weak or electromagnetic.

Is the rotation caused by some pseudo force which comes into action because of the non-inertial frames that are involved? One argument against this is pseudo-force is not supposed to do any work if observed from a non-inertial frame. Here we clearly see the gyroscope flipping in the lab frame which implies work is done.

I came to know this problem while discussing with a Professor in my department.

Comment: the dynamics of gyroscope motion are well-understood; that is to say, this is a solved problem. the forces at work are purely mechanical. have a look at wikipedia or any first-year engineering dynamics book for a complete treatment..